# Diagonalizability and Topology

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

In an exchange with one of my math professors, I was told that diagonalizability can differ depending on whether one is dealing with the field of real numbers or the complex numbers.

I learned in Real Analysis last term that concepts like "compactness" similarly vary over different fields.

My question given the above is simply this - is diagonalizability of matrices  (or their underlying linear systems) also a topological concept, or related to topology in some way?  I have not taken topology (only linear algebra) so I apologize in advance if this is an obvious/stupid question.

Comment: matrix diagonalization involves finding eigenvalues, which are solutions of a polynomial equation, which could have complex but not real solutions

Comment: Diagonalizability is an *algebraic* issue: solution of polynomial equations and solutions of systems of linear equations. The reason diagonalizability may differ depending on the field of definition is that polynomials with coefficients in a field $F$ may have fewer solutions in $F$ than in a larger field $K$ (e.g., a rotation of $90^{\circ}$ about the origin has characteristic equation $x^2+1=0$, which has no solutions over $F=\mathbb{R}$ but two distinct ones over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent responses!  I think I am wrongly conflating the concept of a mathematical phenomenon "over a field" to topology.  Thank you again.

Comment: Oops; of course I meant "two distinct ones over $\mathbb{C}$", not "over $\mathbb{Q}$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, sort of. In order for a square matrix $M$ to be diagonalizable over a field $F$ its [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) need to exist over $F$; equivalently, its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) needs to have all of its roots in $F$. $M$ can have any (monic) characteristic polynomial, thanks to the existence of [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Over $\mathbb{R}$ there are matrices such as rotation matrices

$$R_{\theta} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$$

which don't have real eigenvalues (for most values of $\theta$), or equivalently whose characteristic polynomials don't have roots over $\mathbb{R}$. However, by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) every polynomial with real or complex coefficients has all of its roots over $\mathbb{C}$, so this difficulty disappears over $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. all rotation matrices are diagonalizable).

The connection to topology is that many [proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra) make use of topological ideas, and some of them explain why FTA is true for $\mathbb{C}$ but not $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of topological differences between them, the most basic one being that $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$-dimensional but $\mathbb{C}$ is $2$-dimensional. One such proof involves applying the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) to the [complex projective spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space) $\mathbb{CP}^n$; if you try to apply the proof to the [real projective spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space) $\mathbb{RP}^n$ it will succeed in odd dimensions (corresponding to the fact that every polynomial of odd degree over $\mathbb{R}$ has a real root) but fail in even dimensions (a polynomial of even degree over $\mathbb{R}$ can have no real roots).

Comment: Thank you very much for this thoughtful response.  Some of the concepts at the end of your post I am unfamiliar with at this stage but I will look into them.  The good rotation matrix example aided my understanding as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Root: it's not one of the easier proofs of FTA to understand; I recommend reading through the linked MO thread which contains many proofs, some of which use more or less only basic analysis, but which still highlight topological differences between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.